# For backbone models with one-to-many relationships, does it make a performance-difference to store the "many" models in array rather than Collection?

Tags: javascript, optimization, backbone.js

Given models **User** and **Comments** being populated such that a user may have many comments...I have a view in which I want each User model to be aware of its comments, for fast lookup. But I don't necessarily need all of the features of Collection.

On the other hand, since I use Collections to store any kind of group of models, I would like to stick to using collections for consistency sake.

My question is: is there any kind of significant performance advantage in just keeping an array of Models, rather than a Collection of models even when said collection has no event bindings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Network wise no, you could be bringing down the exact same JSON anyway.

CPU wise, I would say any performance advantage would be extremely minimal. When you load a collection it iterates through each item in the array, converts the element to a model, binds to all model events and adds it to the models property which is an array of models. You wouldn't see any impact from this unless you had a very high number of total comments. Have a look at the [source](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/docs/backbone.html) it's very readable.

Of course the only way to know the actual performance impact is to test it. It should be pretty easy to setup, you'd just need backbone.js, your User & Comments models/collections and JSON to load into the collections.